# Java Persistence and Foxpro

Tags: java, persistence, eclipselink, foxpro

Has anyone use java persistence with a foxpro database?  I am using Eclipselink 2.3.2 and JPA 2.0.3 to connect to a foxpro 9 database that is also used by a foxpro application.

The problem that i am running into is that our customer keeps getting 'Record is not Locked' exceptions in our java application.  This then causes a problem in the foxpro app.  The only solution we have found to fix it is to restart the java app and everything works fine.  We can't reproduce this in house.

They are running on Windows Server 2008R2 on a virtual server.
If anyone has any experience with persistence and foxpro it would be a big help.

Comment: What version of FoxPro are you using and what database driver? You might want to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2238659/read-foxpro-db-using-php-java)

Comment: Are the server and any Windows 7 machines involved all service-packed up? There were problems a while back with DBF/CDX tables caused by SMB 2 being in use.

Comment: I am using Visual Foxpro 9 and the vfpodbc driver, latest version.  Everything seems to work fine 90% of the time.  I would like not to have to totally rewrite what I have done because one day we will be moving to MSSQL. As far as I know the servers are kept up to date with all service packs.

Comment: From what I have found is that it probably would be best to use a different strategy, especially if you have multiple apps taking to the same file based database.